# hacer que aparezca la serie de sus divisiones de los números del arreglo

Tags: array, c

al momento de hacer las divisiones de los números ingresados en el arreglo no me sale bien el resultado de la división de tolos los números del arreglo
un ejemplo si ingreso 2/2/3/4/5/1/1/1/1/1=0.0166666667
y es lo que no me sale

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
int numeros[10];
long int i,a;
double p,l;
a=0;
printf("teclea los numeros que desea saber su suma su resta y su divicion \n");
printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------\n\n");

for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
printf("teclea los diez dijitos que deseas en el arreglo:");
scanf("%i",&numeros[i]);
printf("\n");
}
p=1;l=1;
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    if(i<9)
    printf("%i/",numeros[i]);
    if(i==9)
    printf("%i",numeros[i]);
    p=numeros[i]/p;
}
printf("=%.10lf",p);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de ingresar los números a tu arreglo haz lo siguiente:

```
double resultado = numeros[0];

for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
{
   resultado = resultado / numeros[i];
}

//Imprimir resultado;
```

Declaras la **variable resultado** de tipo **double** y le asignas como valor la primera posición del **arreglo numeros**, posteriormente haces un **ciclo for** que empieza a recorrer el arreglo a partir de la segunda posición y entonces vas haciendo la división de todos los elementos del arreglo. Después de salir del **ciclo for** imprimirías el resultado obtenido.

Analiza este código y adáptalo a tus necesidades.

Comment: muchísimas gracias si me ayudo